# Replace ZFS Disk - and use whole disk

Tags: zfs

I hava a zpool, created on FreeBSD years ago - FreeBSD used the whole disks - without partitioning the Disk.

If I want to replace a disk - ubuntu creates partitions on it - now the disk is smaller than the original and I cannot detach the failed one

Is there a way to disable these partitioning on ubuntu?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please [take the tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) to learn how Ask Ubuntu works. Read [how to ask](https://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of your question. Then take a look to [the help center](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) to see if some _on-topic questions_ are already asked.